# How to display SQLite stored data differed by users?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Currently, I have two(2) SQLite tables - User & Engagement.

I have successfully execute my login activity and direct it to a new activity class - CodeActivity.java.

My question is that how do i display list of engagement on the CodeActivity class differed by users as I have specifically attach each users to different engagement.

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name=uname.getText().toString();
            String password=pswd.getText().toString();

            int id= checkUser(new User(name,password));
            if(id==-1)
            {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Alert");
                builder.setMessage("Username or Password is wrong.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        dialogInterface.dismiss();

                    }
                });

                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
            else
            {
                Intent intentLogin = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CodeActivity.class);
                intentLogin.putExtra("name",name);
                startActivity(intentLogin);
                startActivity(intentLogin);

            }
        }
    });
```

Please help, i've been struggling on this for weeks.

Comment: You should probably rely on a webservice.

Comment: Thank you @Rotwang. i'm learning it by myself and still discovering a lot of things. Arigatooo

Comment: My suggestion is valid if your app is used by different users who must access the same database. So I understood.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store logged in user id into Engagement table & fetch all rows from table with the help of that user id(where logged_in_user_id=='1')

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("Engagement",
            null, "logged_in_user_id" + "=?",
            new String[]{"1"}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. Where should i apply the coding? is it inside the CodeActivity class?

Comment: I'm using DbHandler class to access SQLite database for reading and writing data. I wrote the coding for creating tables and check user function inside DbHandler class. Should i code it like this:                  public void EngList()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query("Engagement",
                null, "logged_in_user_id" + "=?",
                new String[]{"1"}, null, null, null);
    }

Comment: method should have return type as Cursor not void if you are writing method inside DbHandler and you have to retrieve those values from that cursor.